# How to stop cloudflare authentications when visiting a site?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, authentication

I have multiple systems running in the same network, but when I try to visit some websites, I always get the [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) authentication captchas. It is really irritating, because I don't face it in my other systems. Plus the captchas don't show up properly in Firefox or Chrome. I tried disabling all Ad-blockers etc. but to no avail, so I have to resort to IE each time to get through the authentication.

The Cloudflare authentication suggested doing a virus scan on the system to avoid seeing the authentication alert in future, but I tried all that to no avail.

Any help guys? Do I need to format my system?

EDIT1: After sometime the cloudfare authentications stopped, don't know why. I am continuing to use the same system and ISP.

Comment: What?  There is nothing malicious about the Cloudflare captchas.  Why would you do a virus scan?

Comment: The problem is now gone, by itself.

Comment: I get it for some websites regularly... but only on my home network

Answer (score 3):

Web sites often get visitors they don't want.  CloudFlare is a service they pay for which acts as a gate -- to challenge anyone coming from an IP address tagged as being undesirable.  The most common example is an IP address coming from a VPN service.  If you connect to your VPN you may be assigned an IP address which was previously used for nefarious activity.  This activity gets the IP on the naughty list and CloudFlare jumps in front of you when you try and access a web site using CloudFlare.  For the VPN user, disconnecting and reconnecting will hopefully get you a clean IP..

Answer (score 1):

It is probably more important to address why you're seeing a [captcha from CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203366080-Why-do-I-see-a-captcha-or-challenge-page-trying-to-visit-a-site-protected-by-CloudFlare-as-a-site-visitor-) in the first place.

Try looking your IP up with the link in the article (general cause).

Comment: The problem is now gone, by itself. I suspected the first issue highlighted in the article, as I had got a new connection from a new ISP.

Comment: The captcha on that page is looping endlessly so I can't access it =/

Comment: Switching from Edge to Chrome got me to see the site. However, none of the things apply to me. Project HoneyPot says my IP is clean AND it is whitelisted

Answer (score 1):

Note that some IP Addresses are static, baked into the device, requiring you to replace the device to get a new IP. I know of no other way to do it in this case

Project Honeypot only shows one blacklisting site, look more in depth at why your IP may be blacklisted at Cisco's Talos Reputation Center:
https://www.talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/

Answer (score 0):

I checked my IP address on:
http://www.projecthoneypot.org/search_ip.php

I saw that it was blacklisted. My ISP provides me with a dynamic IP. So I whitelisted my IP in:
http://www.projecthoneypot.org/white_list.php

For whitelist-reason I selected: Owner of a dynamic IP.
And submitted the form. Then I checked the IP again after about a minute and saw that it was now whitelisted.

After that I tried going to some of the websites which were giving me this captcha problem and I no longer got the captcha.

Comment: I had a clean IP, I did exactly that anyway, and I STILL get catpchas, even when whitelisted and a clean IP